# How to clear all bash variables?

Tags: bash, variable

I like to make command-line bash variables for testing or for other purposes. I give them generic names like `a`, `b`, `var1`... Sometimes I may forget which variables I've already used. Anyway, is there a single command to clear all bash variables? Now after running such a command, I want all bash variables that were defined by the user to become undefined. When `echo $undefinedvariable` is run, the result is a blank line. All built-in variables like `$USER` or `$SHELL` should remain untouched by this command.

Comment: just type: `exec bash`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the bellow command

```
 $ exec bash
```

It will clear all bash variable

Comment: But not exported ones.